# Converting Qt 4.8 to 5 QPluginLoader->instance returns null

Tags: qt, qt5

I’ve written an Application by using QT 4.8.2. It does dynamically load different plugins to provide multiple functions for the user.
Now Qt5 was released and I wanted to convert my project to the newest version.

I got everything to work, except loading the plugin with QPluginLoader->instance(). While using Qt 4.8.2 it worked fine.

->errorString says:
“The file ‘…/plugins/nlprod.dll’ is not a valid Qt plugin.”

That’s my code:

PluginLoader.cpp:

```
//"fileName" contains the name of the .dll
pluginLoader->setFileName(pluginsDir->absoluteFilePath(fileName));

//"a" contains the correct path + name of the .dll
QString a = pluginLoader->fileName();      

//"plugin" is null and success "false"
QObject *plugin = pluginLoader->instance();
bool success = pluginLoader->isLoaded();
```

MyPlugin.h:

```
class NLPro : public QObject, IConnection
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "NLPro" FILE "nlpro.json") // <- New since I've ported to Qt 5
    Q_INTERFACES(IConnection)
...
}
```

MyPlugin.cpp:
I’ve deleted the following:

```
Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(NLPro, NLPro);
```

and I’ve added a .json-file with the following content:

```
{ "Keys": [ "NLPro"] }
```

Comment: Remember the plugins you compile using Qt 4 are **not** compatible with  Qt 5. They are version dependent. Compiling your plugin using Qt 5 is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Fixed it:

While

```
TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget(nlpro)
```

worked properly with Qt 4.8 I had to change it to

```
TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget(NLPro)
```

for Qt 5.0